# Generate Meeting Request

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code in Excel that generates a meeting and places it on the Outlook calendar of the recipient.

I would like, instead of sending a meeting that is already accepted, to send a request the recipient can either accept or decline.

```
Dim outMail As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Set outMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
outMail.Subject = "A new appointment has been booked for me"
outMail.Location = "Your Desk"
outMail.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
outMail.Start = CDate(DateSelected) & Chr(32) & CDate(TimeSelected)
outMail.Duration = 30
outMail.RequiredAttendees = "myemail@hotmail.com"
outMail.Body = "No Reason"
outMail.ReminderSet = True
outMail.Send
Set outMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.respond

You just have to use :

appointmentitem.Respond( *Response* , true)